# What are these finite sequences called?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

For any positive integer $n$, let $I_n$ stand for the set $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots, n\}$.

Let's say that an $n$-sequence $S$ of elements from $I_n$ is *admissible* iff

1. whenever $S$ contains $j \in I_n$, it also contains all of the elements of $I_{j - 1}$; and
2. whenever $S$ contains integers $i < j$, the first occurrence of $i$ appears before the first occurrence of $j$.

For example, there are 5 admissible 3-sequences: $$111, 112, 121, 122, 123,$$ and 15 admissible $4$-sequences: $$1111, 1112, 1121, 1122, 1211, 1212, 1221, 1222, 1123, 1213, 1223, 1231, 1232, 1233, 1234.$$

Of course, it is straightforward to generalize the idea of such $n$-sequences to any linearly ordered set of $n$ elements.

---

**Q:** Is there a standard name for such sequences?

---

(I came across the need to enumerate such sequences in the context of a probability problem.  I hope that, once I have some suitable terminology, I may be able to search for prior results for such sequences.)

Comment: In the future, a great way to find out is to solve for the first 5-10 n's,  then look that sequence up on http://oeis.org .    It's very rare that you'll come across an enumeration problem that isn't equivalent to _something_ there

Comment: @Alan: I realized precisely this after I had already posted my question!  In fact, I did pretty much what you described (except that I just entered the sequence directly into Google), and got the answer to my question.  Unfortunately, JMP beat me to the punch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

$$1, 1, 2, 5, 15, 52, 203, 877, 4140, 21147, 115975, 678570, 4213597$$

[A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110)